# HTML5 video - show/hide controls programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I am looking for a way to show or hide HTML5 video controls at will via javascript. The controls are currently only visible when the video starts to play

Is there a way to do this with the native video controls?

I'm using google chrome browser.

Comment: Removing the controls hides the audio all together, so you will need to add the `autoplay` attribute or play the audio programmatically.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
<video id="myvideo">
  <source src="path/to/movie.mp4" />
</video>

<p onclick="toggleControls();">Toggle</p>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");

function toggleControls() {
  if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) {
     video.removeAttribute("controls")   
  } else {
     video.setAttribute("controls","controls")   
  }
}
</script>
```

See it working on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgLds/

Comment: Any ideas on how to achieve this behavior in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to do it:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("my-video")    
myVideo.controls = false;
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/otnfccgu/2/

See all available properties, methods and events here: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_av_dom.asp

Answer (score 3):

[CARL LANGE](http://flax.ie/how-to-get-hidden-autoplaying-audio-in-html5-on-ios/) also showed how to get hidden, autoplaying audio in html5 on a iOS device. Works for me.

In HTML,

```
<div id="hideme">
    <audio id="audioTag" controls>
        <source src="/path/to/audio.mp3">
    </audio>
</div>
```

with JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var audioEl = document.getElementById("audioTag");
    audioEl.load();
    audioEl.play();
};
</script>
```

In CSS,

```
#hideme {display: none;}
```