# how to insert audio in a webpage and hide the control in html

Tags: html, audio, controls

how can I insert local audio without displaying any control(if we can show only volume button then better) which loops itself continuously...?
I tried embed tag, iframe tag, audio tag but no one is perfect some works on edge but not on chrome...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you hide HTML5 Audio controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697724/how-do-you-hide-html5-audio-controls)

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding it using CSS by setting the 'display' to 'none'.

```
audio { 
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Web Audio API* to play a sound without visible control in the html page.
There is [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loop) option you can activate to play in a loop.

```
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

fetch('sample.wav')
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer, data => {
      source.buffer = data;
      source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      source.loop = true;
      source.start(0);
    })
  })
```

If you need, you can add a volume control with the help of a `gainNode` and a range slider for example.

Note some browser implementations prevent playing audio until user explicitly allows it.