# Hide Video Controls Until User Hover Over Video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

i'm trying to hide the video controls on my video, until the user hover over the video, then the controls shows up. Any idea or advice? Thanks. **And I've got more than one video.**

HTML:

```
<div class="item spoon burger"><video width="300" height="auto" controls><source src="videos/sruthi.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
```

Comment: What things have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 video - show/hide controls programtically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399412/html5-video-show-hide-controls-programtically)

Comment: i tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/dySyv/1/. but it removes the controls only when click

Comment: Take a look at my example. It is done via hover.

Comment: hmm i dont think it's a duplicate, because i'm trying to do it when the user hover on the video itself.

Comment: Note that as of now, if you have both `controls` and `autoplay` attributes on, most browsers/OSes will automatically show/hide on hover/unhover. So depending on your needs, this all might be unnecessary. https://jsfiddle.net/ubvLxzp2/show

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We can accomplish this through just a couple lines of jQuery, making use of [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/A2L2N/)

<del>$('#myvideo').hover(function toggleControls() {
        if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) {
            video.removeAttribute("controls")
        } else {
            video.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
        }
    })</del>

**Edit** I mistakenly left the variable `video` in the code above. I changed it to `this` so that you won't have to manage variables that grab an ID.

```
$('#myvideo').hover(function toggleControls() {
    if (this.hasAttribute("controls")) {
        this.removeAttribute("controls")
    } else {
        this.setAttribute("controls", "controls")
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<video width="300" height="auto" id="myvideo">
    <source src="#" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

---

**Update:**
You mentioned that you have several videos. So you can use this same logic, and just add additional selectors into `$( )`. Here's an example:

```
$('#yourID1, #yourID2, #yourID3').hover(function toggleControls() { ...
```

Doing that will *listen* or wait until it detects that you're hovering over one of those IDs.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/A2L2N/1/)

Comment: so it works on jsfiddle, but not on my browser. Is that because i've got more than one video, so getElementByID won't work?

Comment: Are you including jQuery on your page? Are you updating the `$('#myvideo')` part of the code? I'm not sure if you're familiar with jQuery at all, but that is your element selector. '#insertYourIDHere'. And if you have multiple videos, you can pass in multiple ID's there. I'll update the code above.

Comment: thanks for your help, it's working. No, i'm not too familiar with jQuery, still pretty new to it.

Comment: using if statement has its flaws for example i the user rushes to hover the video the if statements effect will be inverted, hence showing the controls when the user is outside the video surface

Comment: @Wandile Is there a better way to do it then without the `if`? Please share. Thank you.

Comment: @purple11111 i just did this simple jQuery `hover` in | out to toggle https://jsfiddle.net/Wandile/hmL837zn/ you can remove the `controls` attribute by default should you wish for the controls not to show by default

Comment: In Firefox (didnt test other browsers) the controls are "flickering" whe you move cursor.

Comment: HOw would you do this for all classes

Comment: all videos in a class*

Comment: @Skyler, you would only need to modify your `selector` for the element that you want to add this functionality to. Replace the ``#yourID1, #yourID2, #yourID3'` with a reference to your `class`.

Answer (score 13):

One issue with @EnigmaRM's answer is that if jQuery somehow misses a `hover` event, the controls can be toggled the "wrong" way - that is, they disappear on mouse enter and reappear on mouse leave.

Instead, we can ensure that the controls *always* appear and disappear correctly with `event.type`:

```
$("#myvideo").hover(function(event) {
    if(event.type === "mouseenter") {
        $(this).attr("controls", "");
    } else if(event.type === "mouseleave") {
        $(this).removeAttr("controls");
    }
});
```

Comment: This can be extended to cover multiple video players if you assign a class to the player rather than a CSS ID.  ```class='myvideo'``` and then change the selector to ```(".myvideo")```

Answer (score 8):

Untested, but I believe this would work.  It uses JavaScript instead of CSS.

```
<div class="item spoon burger"><video id="videoElement" width="300" height="auto"><source src="videos/sruthi.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window) {
        function setupVideo()
        {
            var v = document.getElementById('videoElement');
            v.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { this.controls = true; }, false);
            v.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { this.controls = false; }, false);
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', setupVideo, false);
    })(window);
</script>
```

Comment: I tested this solution: it works and it does not require Jquery, wich is great. Thanks @sean-bright!

Comment: This was a useful start! I had to swap `this` for `v` in the callback, set the property to `'controls'` instead of `true`, and add a line to disable controls on load. Working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299017/1079110

Comment: You needed to change `this` to `v` because `this` [has a different meaning when used in a function vs. an arrow function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-and-arrow-functions).

Comment: Also, using `'controls'` instead of `true` is just implicitly converting `'controls'` to `true` due to Javascript's implicit type conversions. [The `controls` property is a boolean, not a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controls).

Answer (score 4):

```html
<script>
function setupVideos() {
  for (const video of document.querySelectorAll('video')) {
    video.controls = false
    video.addEventListener('mouseover', () => { video.controls = 'controls' })
    video.addEventListener('mouseout', () => { video.controls = false })
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', setupVideos, false)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below, you don't need a separate javascript section (if that is a concern, which is the case sometimes).  Just simply use `onmouseover="this.play();this.setAttribute('controls','controls')"` and `onmouseout="this.load();this.removeAttribute('controls')"`

If you don't want it to reset to a poster image, then you can get rid of the this.load.

```
<div class="img_placeholder">
         <video width="350" height="250" loop preload="none" poster="../assets/icon-32.png" onmouseover="this.play();this.setAttribute('controls','controls')" onmouseout="this.load();this.removeAttribute('controls')">
         <source src="../assets/bear.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
         </video>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A previous post explained how to do it this way [HTML5 video - show/hide controls programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399412/html5-video-show-hide-controls-programtically)

```
<video id="myvideo">
  <source src="path/to/movie.mp4" />
</video>

<p onclick="toggleControls();">Toggle</p>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");

function toggleControls() {
  if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) {
     video.removeAttribute("controls")   
  } else {
     video.setAttribute("controls","controls")   
  }
}
</script>
```

Check if their solution works for you! Please +1 them if so!

Comment: While the goal is similar, this doesn't answer OP's question. He wants it on hover. And that previous post was already linked to in the initial comments.

Comment: @EnigmaRM That comment was posted after this answer.