# Hide <video> controls on page load

Tags: html, video, controls

I am a complete novice to coding so please excuse my ignorance. I am embedding a video using the  tag which everything works as it should. I was wondering if there is a way to have the controls be hidden when the page loads and have them show up when the mouse is hovered over the video; like it does once it is playing. Any way to do this?

Btw: this is being entered into an html content box in a document editor (BEE)

THANK YOU

EDIT: attached are pictures of what it looks like where I can put the code. Again, I have minimal experience with this stuff. It is an html content box in a document editor.

[What html box selection looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhFrf.png)
[Once html box is added to editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgAkM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: [HTML5 video - show/hide controls programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399412/html5-video-show-hide-controls-programmatically/42538700)

```
<video id="myvideo">
  <source src="path/to/movie.mp4" />
</video>

<p onclick="toggleControls();">Toggle</p>

<script>
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");

function toggleControls() {
  if (video.hasAttribute("controls")) {
     video.removeAttribute("controls")   
  } else {
     video.setAttribute("controls","controls")   
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just uploaded a few pics to where the code would go. I pasted it in there and changed the src to my video url but didnt work. any help? TIA

Comment: What you say it didn't work, what do you see? My guess is that the js part was removed from your editor. Try to put the script tag portion in a place where it allows it to be executed

Comment: It shows everything but if i click on toggle it doesnt play

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dgLds/ it works here so if you copied the code it should work. Do you have the Jquery library linked?