# How to hide the black loading spinner in a HTML5 video tag?

Tags: html5-video

I am playing a m3u8 video in HTML5 video tag using HLS.js.

The video plays fine on clicking play button but until I click the play button the video player keeps on showing the black coloured loading spinner in the middle of the video player. I want to get rid of that spinner completely.

Can any one help me achieving this using JS or CSS or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to set `HTMLVideoElement.controls` attribute on the `<video />` to false to use your custom controls

Comment: The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399412/html5-video-show-hide-controls-programmatically) provide more options