# How can I hide audio controls from HTML5 video on all browsers?

Tags: css

I tried this code but it is not working for firefox

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {  display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {  display: none; }

Comment: This might helpful https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Comment: That your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399412/html5-video-show-hide-controls-programtically